# CoreData + CloudKit compilation problem in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, ios15

I'm trying to validate by app with the latest Xcode 13 RC.

I found out that what was building well on Xcode 12, is not longer compiling on 13 RC.

For example, I started getting:  `Cannot find type 'CKRecord' in scope` in a class that already has the `import CoreData` statement. In iOS 14 I didn't have to import CloudKit.

If I add the `import CloudKit` statement, it compiles fine and runs on a iOS 15 simulator but it no longer works on iOS 14. I started getting the following runtime error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/_CoreData_CloudKit.framework/_CoreData_CloudKit
> Referenced from: /Users/andrei/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8554B734-4894-4DD0-A8FA-6C20983F3A49/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/71012125-8F7B-437A-8E59-78F588AA33FD/XXX.app/XXX
> Reason: image not found
> dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

reproducible [here](https://github.com/andreimateiro/ios15sdkbug).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: remove the CK references and the imports. I personally migrated to Realm. No more CK for me, ever!

Comment: Thanks. I saw your other question with a link to this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682925?page=1#687848022. I removed the the line specifying the private database scope. I don't blame you. If it weren't a hobby app, I would consider migrating too